# How to eliminate angularjs errors due to svg circles?

Tags: angularjs, svg, digest

I'm new to AngularJS and while I like its feature set, its learning curve as been steep. Currently I'm working with generating an SVG graph based on data returned from a mySQL server (as a JSON object of course). With the help of other stackoverflow posts I've overcome the errors based on the SVG trying to render path points before Angular binds them ('points' vs. 'ng-points'). However, I'm running into another problem that involves Angular's 10 iteration limit when using ng-repeat.

My graph is similar to Google Analytics: a couple polygons and a series of circles for each point. Following is the template. As is, this throws the 10 $digest() iterations error. It works visually, but the console shows the errors.

```
<svg width="100%" height="300" style="overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="rgb(245,245,245)" />
  <polygon fill="#ddf" ng-points="{{line}}" />
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="#bbe" stroke-width="3" ng-points="{{line}}" />

  <g ng-repeat="point in xy">
    <circle ng-cx="{{xy[$index][0]}}" ng-cy="{{xy[$index][1]}}" r="5" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Data for each point is pulled from mySQL and formatted with a controller method. {{line}} are the points as a string. {{xy}} are the points as an array/object (I've tried using both) with nested arrays to match the cx/cy format for SVG circles.

```
xy = [["0","300"],["100","130"],["200","109"], ...]
```

My thought is that I need to build each circle within a directive and then attach it to the element (or compile?) but when I try to access the array from within a link or compile is when I have trouble. The array (or object) exists and I can open it with the console.log however trying to drill in from within the directive and I start getting empty strings. So here's the state of the directive I'm trying to use

```
directives.ngGraph = function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      line: "=",
      xy: "="
    },
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'partials/graph.html',
    link: function(scope, attrs) {
      console.log(scope.xy)
    }
  };
};
```

In the above scenario, logging scope.xy returns an array as expected, but logging scope.xy[0] returns an empty string: " ".

So my question: how do I loop through the nested array linked in the attribute and attach each iteration to the template in the cx/cy format that circles require?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need $index, as you have each actual element in your local variable "point" during iteration. Also, don't use ng-prefix for the attributes cx and cy, instead treat it all as raw HTML and only use angular {{ }} syntax:

```
<g ng-repeat="point in xy">
    <circle cx="{{point[0]}}" cy="{{point[1]}}" r="5" />
</g>
```

See plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/zzXiAEaRsnst3Fuvs1IF?p=preview